# showing {} in console when the form is submitting using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, handlebars.js

Tring to get data from a form to the consol using node js

from a form the data is submitted using node js and print it in the console .but it shows {}.
what does this mean
how to solve it

my form :

```
    
            <form action="/admin/add-faq" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">


                <label for="">Question </label>
                <input type="text" name="Name" class="form-control">

                <label for="">Answer</label>
                <input type="text" name="Category" class="form-control">


              

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Submit</button>
            </form>
   
</section> 


____________________________________________________________________________




nodejs file :

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('adminintro',{admin:true})
  
  });

router.get('/add-faq',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('faqadmin',{admin:true})
   });
router.post('/add-faq',(req,res)=>{
 console.log(req.body);
})
 
 
module.exports = router;

____________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use body-parser in the middleware to expose the `req.body` for the incoming request.

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

then in your file include this line

```
const bp = require("body-parser") 

app.use(bp.urlencoded({extended : false }) ;
app.use(bp.json() )
```

with this you can see the `req.body` values